# Pass DOCKER_OPTS to Daemon.json.j2

Tags: docker, ansible

I am new to ansible & docker, how can i pass the DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375" to /etc/init.d/docker in ansible using the file daemon.json.j2

file structure:
templates 
  --> daemon.json.j2

daemon.json.j2

```
{
{% if docker_use_dnsmasq %}
  "dns": ["172.17.0.1"],
{% endif %}
{% if docker_use_tcp %}
   "hosts": ["fd://", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"],
{% endif %}
  "storage-driver": "{{ docker_driver }}",
  "log-driver": "journald"
}
```

ansible:

```
- name: Add Docker config
  template:
    src: daemon.json.j2
    dest: /etc/docker/daemon.json
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644
  when: 'docker_is_dockerized == false'

- name: Change the value
  lineinfile:
    path: /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
    regexp: 'ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://'
    line: 'ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375'
  when: 'docker_is_dockerized == false'
```

docker.service

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-03-03 21:13:41 UTC; 3min 25s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1747 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1747 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 03 21:13:41 ip-10-150-4-45 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 03 21:13:41 ip-10-150-4-45 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 03 21:13:41 ip-10-150-4-45 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 03 21:13:41 ip-10-150-4-45 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 03 21:13:41 ip-10-150-4-45 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Mar 03 21:13:41 ip-10-150-4-45 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 03 21:13:41 ip-10-150-4-45 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 03 21:13:41 ip-10-150-4-45 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? The list of available options is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).

Comment: Please include any errors you have encountered.

Comment: @BMitch i have updated what i tried.

Comment: Those logs aren't giving any errors. I've taken a guess at the most likely error, but you'll need to include a `journalctl -u docker` if the below answer doesn't resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the host field with daemon.json, you'll need to setup a systemd override to remove the host options being passed on the command line. With your ansible scripts, that would be the following task:

```
- name: 'Update systemd unit overrides for Docker'
  copy:
    content: |
      [Service]
      # next two lines needed to allow /etc/docker/daemon.json to adjust hosts
      ExecStart=
      ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
    dest: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
    force: yes
    owner: root
    mode: 0644
```

For those doing this without ansible, the above creates a file called `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf` containing:

```
[Service]
# next two lines needed to allow /etc/docker/daemon.json to adjust hosts
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
```

After creating that file, you'll need to `systemctl daemon-reload`. To reset the failure limit, you'll need to `systemctl reset-failed`. And lastly, to start docker, you have `systemctl start docker`.